# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, eclipse-juno, lifecycleexception

I've gone through a lot of similar posts and I was unable to find anything that's a help.iam new to java web development

> Oct 07, 2016 6:52:14 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.37 Oct 07, 2016 6:52:14 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   built:          Sep 1 2016 10:01:52 UTC Oct 07, 2016 6:52:14 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   number:         8.0.37.0 Oct 07, 2016 6:52:14 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS Name:
>   Windows 10 Oct 07, 2016 6:52:14 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS
>   Version:            10.0 Oct 07, 2016 6:52:14 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   Architecture:          amd64 Oct 07, 2016 6:52:14 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Java Home:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65 Oct 07, 2016 6:52:14 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
>   Version:           1.8.0_65-b17 Oct 07, 2016 6:52:14 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
>   Vendor:            Oracle Corporation Oct 07, 2016 6:52:14 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   CATALINA_BASE:
>   F:\javaWebDevelopment.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
>   Oct 07, 2016 6:52:14 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   CATALINA_HOME:         C:\tomcat Oct 07, 2016 6:52:14 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument:
>   -Dcatalina.base=F:\javaWebDevelopment.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
>   Oct 07, 2016 6:52:14 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\tomcat Oct 07, 2016 6:52:14 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument:
>   -Dwtp.deploy=F:\javaWebDevelopment.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
>   Oct 07, 2016 6:52:14 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\tomcat\endorsed Oct 07, 2016
>   6:52:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 Oct 07, 2016 6:52:14 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFO: The
>   APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal
>   performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_65/bin/server;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_65/bin;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_65/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL
>   SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL
>   SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform
>   Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web
>   Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows
>   Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Dinuka_M\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10;C:\Users\Dinuka_M\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;F:\banda\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\eclipse;;.
>   Oct 07, 2016 6:52:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO:
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] Oct 07, 2016 6:52:17 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector INFO:
>   Using a shared selector for servlet write/read Oct 07, 2016 6:52:17 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] Oct 07, 2016 6:52:17 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector INFO:
>   Using a shared selector for servlet write/read Oct 07, 2016 6:52:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
>   processed in 5256 ms Oct 07, 2016 6:52:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service Catalina Oct 07, 2016 6:52:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.37 Oct 07, 2016 6:52:17 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor WARNING:
>   The XML schema [web-app_3_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very
>   likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled. Oct 07,
>   2016 6:52:17 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory
>   locationFor WARNING: The XML schema [web-fragment_3_0.xsd] could not
>   be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML
>   validation is enabled. Oct 07, 2016 6:52:17 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor WARNING:
>   The XML schema [web-common_3_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very
>   likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled. Oct 07,
>   2016 6:52:17 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory
>   locationFor WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_6.xsd] could not be found.
>   This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is
>   enabled. Oct 07, 2016 6:52:17 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor WARNING:
>   The XML schema [jsp_2_2.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely
>   to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled. Oct 07, 2016
>   6:52:17 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory
>   locationFor WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_web_services_1_3.xsd]
>   could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML
>   validation is enabled. Oct 07, 2016 6:52:17 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor WARNING:
>   The XML schema [javaee_web_services_client_1_3.xsd] could not be
>   found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation
>   is enabled. Oct 07, 2016 6:52:17 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor WARNING:
>   The XML schema [web-app_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very
>   likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled. Oct 07,
>   2016 6:52:17 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory
>   locationFor WARNING: The XML schema [web-fragment_3_1.xsd] could not
>   be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML
>   validation is enabled. Oct 07, 2016 6:52:17 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor WARNING:
>   The XML schema [web-common_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very
>   likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled. Oct 07,
>   2016 6:52:17 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory
>   locationFor WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_7.xsd] could not be found.
>   This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is
>   enabled. Oct 07, 2016 6:52:17 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor WARNING:
>   The XML schema [jsp_2_3.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely
>   to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled. Oct 07, 2016
>   6:52:17 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory
>   locationFor WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_web_services_1_4.xsd]
>   could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML
>   validation is enabled. Oct 07, 2016 6:52:17 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor WARNING:
>   The XML schema [javaee_web_services_client_1_4.xsd] could not be
>   found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation
>   is enabled. Oct 07, 2016 6:52:18 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal SEVERE: A child
>   container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1898)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1131)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:783)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Oct 07, 2016 6:52:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   startInternal SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Oct 07, 2016 6:52:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is
>   unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to
>   start component [StandardServer[8005]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardService[Catalina]]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     ... 11 more
>
> Oct 07, 2016 6:52:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFO:
>   Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] Oct 07, 2016 6:52:18 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-8009"] Oct 07, 2016 6:52:18 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal INFO: Stopping
>   service Catalina Oct 07, 2016 6:52:18 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFO: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] Oct 07, 2016 6:52:18 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy SEVERE: Failed to destroy
>   end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:551)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
>
> Oct 07, 2016 6:52:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
>   INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] Oct 07, 2016 6:52:18
>   PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy SEVERE: Failed to
>   destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:551)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

"

this is my lib[image]

tomcat 6 works in fine with eclips juno.then i install mars jst server adapters and jst server adapters extension to juno. then add tomcat 8.but it cant run through eclips. manually tomcat can be run in localhost 8181.

Solved

i choose java jdk folder path instead java jre..my problem was solved ..thanks

Comment: please iam spending three day for this error ... any ideas much appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose Java JDK folder path instead of Java JRE. My problem was solved ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have used "invoker" in my web.xml and after too much investigation i found that its no longer after tomcat 6.

remove this invoker and mapped all the servlet with /servlet/servlet.class.fully.qualified.name